# Need of periodic function for Fourier spectral method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation-theory

While applying Fourier spectral method to solve any PDE, why do we need the function to be periodic?
And, similarly, why do we switch to Chebyshev spectral method if the function is non-periodic?

I can assume that the second part of the question is related to the Chebyshev grid. But, the grid comes into the picture if we want a fast computation that uses FFT. I am unable to process different thoughts.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fourier spectral methods are _inherently_ periodic due to the basis being $e^{i k x}$ and so we use them to solve PDEs with periodic boundary conditions because they are ready made for it. We use Chebyshev spectral methods for non-periodic functions because they minimize the $\infty$ norm and almost always give the best approximation (see Trefethen '_Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice_', chapter 10).

Comment: We use the Chebyshev grid because, to quote Trefethen, 'polynomial interpolants in equispaced points in $[a, b]$ have very poor approximation properties, but interpolants in Chebyshev points, which cluster near $[a, b]$, are excellent'. This is because polynomial interpolation in equispaced points is exponentially ill conditioned. I suggest you read [Boyds book on spectral methods](https://depts.washington.edu/ph506/Boyd.pdf) if you haven't already; once you have read that, read the book listed above by Trefethen.